# ReCaptcha problem after migrating 1.9.4.0 > 2.3.3

Tags: magento2, magento-1.9, migration

We've been trying to migrate our current M1.9.4.0 to M2.3.3 but we ran into an exception we can't seem to solve/ get rid of. This occurs wherever we go on the website; we cannot access the storefront or admin. The errors says:

```
Exception #0 (ReflectionException): Class Magento\Captcha\Model\Recaptcha does not exist
```

The full message: https://pastebin.com/nGqMtnKJ

We tried all the solutions we could find and already posted on the official Magento forum but so far the suggested solutions did not have any effect. For reference: https://community.magento.com/t5/Magento-2-x-Programming/Migration-M1-to-M2-but-ReflectionException-Class-Magento-Captcha/td-p/325657

Anyone got an idea what might cause this? Thank you!

Comment: Can you please confirm **vendor/magento/module-captcha** this directory available or not in your vendor ?

Comment: The folder module-captcha in vendor/magento does exist.

Comment: Please check my answer and let me know if it helps! Thanks

Comment: Recapcha is not available in magento, you have to set it up.

Answer (score 0):

run di compile

```
*php bin/magento setup:di:compile*
```

It displayed there is syntax error and showed line number if any. Then updgrade,

```
*php bin/magento setup:upgrade*
```

and deploy,

```
*php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy*
```

for developer mode,

```
*php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f*
```

May be helpful.

Comment: Thank you. I ran these commands and it didn't return any warnings or errors whatsoever and executed perfectly. Problem still persists

Answer (score 0):

Try to run below command in your CLI

```
composer update
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

Hope this will help you!

Comment: You got any solution here ?

Comment: No, we tried all solutions and more but nothing worked. We ended up going with another migration tool and it pretty much worked flawlessly.

Comment: @jxsh, Okay that's Great! :)

Comment: Thank you for your time and help though :)

Comment: You're always welcome Buddy ;)